# How to view or delete my Yahoo Search History without logging in?

Tags: yahoo-search

I want to view and delete some items from the search history on Yahoo. According to [View and manage Yahoo Search history](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/search/SLN2203.html) on Yahoo's help pages, I have to log in in order to view my search history.

Is it possible to view and delete entries from Yahoo! Search **without an account or log in**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Yahoo's help article is a bit misleading. You don't need to log in to view your search history. Simply visit http://search.yahoo.com/history to view and manage your Yahoo! Search history.